# A module $M$ is finitely generated if and only if any increasing chain $M_i$ of submodules with union $M$ stabilizes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

I found this statement in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_module).

> A module $M$ is finitely generated if and only if any increasing chain $M_i$ of submodules with union $M$ stabilizes.

This is essentially the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246182). But the answer there (in the comment) refers to finitely generated objects in a categorical sense. Can someone provide an elementary proof of this statement? (I know how to prove the “$\Longrightarrow$” part, but not the “$\Longleftarrow$” part.)

PS. This is NOT a question about Noetherian Module. We only say that any chain of submodules of $M$: $M_1\subset M_2\subset\cdots$, which satisfies $M = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty M_i$, will eventually stabilizes.

Comment: The same proof works, word for word. That's why I closed this.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry to bother you again, sir. I've read your answer there, but still didn't see what you mean by “same proof”. If you mean: if $M$ is not finitely generated, we can find $\langle n_1\rangle \subsetneq \langle n_1, n_2 \rangle \subsetneq \cdots$, but the union of this chain is not necessarily $M$ (when $M$ doesn't have a countable set of generators) and hence this chain doesn't have to stop. So, no contradiction at this stage. Or do you mean some application of Zorn's lemma?

Comment: If $M$ is finitely generated, all generators are found in some intermediate step. In the converse, go transfinite. The statement doesn't say "increasing sequence", it says "increasing chain".